# Probability: Store opening time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

Smith has a small booth where he sells lottery tickets. Customers arrive according to a Poisson
process of rate  $\lambda$= 1 per minute. He will close the shop on the 1st occasion that $a$  minutes
have elapsed since the last customer arrived.

let $X$ denote the first time when the gap between the arrival of
two consecutive customers is less than a. Find $E(X)$

**Attempt:**

I think $X$ is just exponential distributed, but $X=0$ for $x>a$. So $E[X]=\int_0^a\lambda x e^{-\lambda x}dx$.

What do you guys think?

Comment: The problem talks about closing shop the first time the gap is $a$ minutes, but the question asks that the gap be less than $a$. Is this correct?

Comment: This question has multiple parts. This is the second part, which is what I am asking right now.

Comment: Let $Y$ denote the first arrival time, then *the first time when the gap between the arrival of two consecutive customers is less than $a$* is $X=Y$ on $Y<a$ and $X=Y+X'$ on $Y>a$, where $X'$ is independent of $Y$ and distributed like $X$. Thus, $X=Y+X'\mathbf 1_{Y>a}$, $E(X)=E(Y)+E(X')P(Y>a)=E(Y)+E(X)P(Y>a)$, and $E(X)=E(Y)/P(Y<a)$. Finally, note that $E(Y)=1/\lambda$ and $P(Y<a)=1-e^{-\lambda a}$. Likewise, the first time $Z$ when the gap between the arrival of two consecutive customers is more than $a$ is such that $E(Z)=E(Y)/P(Y>a)=e^{\lambda a}/\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is not the length of the gap, $X$ is the time when the length of the gap is first of greater than $a$.  Call it a "long-gap", while a lesser length is a "short-gap".

To clarify:  Suppose *some* customers have arrived, all with a short-gaps before each and its previous, and then another customer arrives after a long-gap.   $X$ is the time of arrival of that customer.

Thus $X$ is the expected time a *long-gap* plus the expect count of *short-gaps* before the first *long-gap* times the expected time of any *short-gap* (since each is iid, and expectation is linear).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~ = & ~ \mathsf E(\mathsf E(\Delta T_{N+1}\mid \Delta T_{N+1}\geq a) + \mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N\Delta T_k\mid\forall k\leq N:\Delta T_k<a))
\\ = & ~ \mathsf E(\Delta T_{\ast}\mid \Delta T_{\ast}\geq a) +\mathsf E(N)\cdot\mathsf E(\Delta T_\ast\mid\Delta T_\ast<a)
\end{align}$$

Now the lengths of each gaps is iid exponentially distributed.

$$\Delta T_\ast \mathop{\sim}\limits^{iid} \mathcal {Exp}(1)$$

The count of *short-gaps* **before** the first *long-gap* is geometrically distributed, with success rate being the probability of a *long-gap*. 
$$N\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(\mathsf P(\Delta T_\ast\geq a))$$

Can you complete?

---

(NB: "count of fails before success" is the $k\in\{0,1,...\}$ version of geometric distribution.)

Answer (score 0):

We're computing $E X$ for $X$ taken as the time Smith closes his store (this is because the question seemed to ask that - recent comment shows differently, but the proof is similar).

The interarrival times are indeed IID exponential with rate $1$. Denote them by $T_1,T_2,\dots$ ($T_1$ time the first customer arrives, $T_2$ time between first and second customer, etc.).

Let $M=\min\{n: T_n \ge a\}$. Then

1. $M$ is geometric with parameter $ \int_a^{\infty} e^{-t} dt = e^{-a}$.
2. $X = \sum_{i<M} T_i + a$.

Now compute $EX$. We do this by conditioning on $M$:

$$ E X = \sum_{j=1}^\infty E[ X |M=j] P(M=j)= a + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (j-1) E [T_1| M=j] P(M=j).$$

Where the last equality is due to the fact that conditioned on $\{M=j\}$, $T_1,\dots ,T_{j-1}$ are IID. Now

$$\{M=j\}=\{T_1 <a\}\cap \{T_2 < a\}\dots \cap \{T_{j-1}<a\}\cap \{T_j\ge a\}.$$

All but the first event in the intersection on the RHS but the first are independent of $T_1$. Therefore for $j>1$  (note that $j=1$ does not contribute in sum above):

$$ E [ T_1 | M=j] =  E [ T_1 | T_1 <a] = \frac{  \int_0^a t e^{-t}dt}{ \int_0^a e^{-t} dt}=\frac{1-e^{-a}(1+a)} {1-e^{-a}}.$$

Putting this back into our formula, we have

$$\begin{align*} E X & = a+ \frac{1-e^{-a}(1+a)} {1-e^{-a}} E (M-1) \\
 & = a + \frac{1-e^{-a}(1+a)} {1-e^{-a}} (e^a-1)\\
& = a + e^a-(1+a)=e^a -1.
\end{align*}$$